# Letter to ascii in sql

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, database, ascii

I have a problem about some letters like e,n,t or "ı"(in turkish). There is no pattern sometimes its occurs sometimes not. Or in a single word one of the "e" is ok but the other one turned to ascii value of e, so its like this "Melike" but it is should be "Melike". Multiple tables in my database in mssql this problem occurs, bu not in every single row most of the records are okay but like %5 of them like this. Default Language of server is english collaction is Turkish_CI_AS. Is there anyone who can help me with that ?

the picture you can see the problem.

[!! look at the problem !!](https://i.hizliresim.com/5DjdrR.png)

Comment: what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: please click the look at the problem link, so you can see the screen shot

Comment: Link for picture returining 403 Forbidden

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your columns has Turkish_CI_AS collation.
In collation names CI is stand for Case insensitive (sql does not care about Capital letters).
And AS is stand for Accent Sensitive. 
Maybe your columns has different collation which is AI accent insensitive. 
Columns , and databases can have different collation then server.
Check you columns and be sure that collation is set to AS

```
select * from sys.all_objects where name=N'myTableName'
SELECT name, collation_name FROM sys.columns WHERE name in ( N'myColumnName' , N'NAZIV') and object_id=idofmytable;
```

Comment: database collation is Turkish_CI_AS and column is also same you see it below.

[screen shot here](https://i.hizliresim.com/1JRyWN.png)